# Eclipse parameterized test freeze with JUnit 4.11

Tags: eclipse, junit, parameterized-unit-test

Configured eclipse indigo SR2 to use junit 4.11 with hamcrest-core-1.3.jar.

Whenever test is run in ide with this:

```
@Parameters(name = "{0}")
```

the JUnit console halts at zero. e.g. "0/100".

It works fine in ide without the name parameter.  `@Parameters //(name = "{0}")`.
It works fine also in command line using ANT with the name parameter.

Tried this on Juno version but the same issue exists. Please help.

Comment: Can we see more code please?

Comment: Thank you Matthew for the interest in helping. Test runs fine w/o the annotation parameter (name={0}).

Comment: Test runs fine w/o the annotation parameter, so culprit can't be the code (30+ test classes, same behavior).  Only inconvenient to comment/uncomment.  My guess is the junit runner plugin is incompatible with junit 4.11.  Have seen others made it work.

Comment: Found the culprit, the "\n" new line character in the first parameter was causing the halt.